# Laravel get user with his heroes

Tags: laravel

My laravel database structure is:

1. users table - with user information
2. user_heroes table - pivot table with `user_id` and `hero_id`

I'm trying to make a new API method to get the user infromation with object named "heroes" with the list of heroes under it.

```
public function getLoggedUser(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->input('token');
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
        //$heroes = $user->heroes; How do I output it with the user infromation?
        return $user;
    }
```

how I can output my user information with his list of heroes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been checking some answers of pivot tables in other stackoverflow questions and I somehow got to it.

The expression looks like this:

```
return $user->with('heroes')->get()->find($user->id);
```

Thanks anyway.. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relationships in the models setup correctly, all you need to do is eager load the heroes and utilize the `Collection`'s `toJson()` method.

```
return $user->with('heroes')->get()->toJson()
```

This will output your user object, which will have a heroes property which will contain all the heroes.

This assumes of course that you want to return json since this is an API and I'm not sure what the other end is expecting.

Comment: I really have no idea why, but it returns all of the users and not only the one assigned to the $user variable.